# Need to get input from a radio button in a JFrame, and use the selected input in another class

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlink

I need to create an application where I need to get a user input from a radio button and then use the selected filename in a different class.I'm not sure how to implement this, beacuse everytime I try to place a getString() method in the MyAction class it gives me a null value. thanks!!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;

public class SelectRadioButton{

    public SelectRadioButton(){

      // Directory path here
      String path = "W:\\materials"; 

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Material Selection");
      JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 4));
      ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();

      String files;
      File folder = new File(path);
      File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); 
      JRadioButton  first;

      for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) 
      {

       if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) 
       {
       files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
           if (files.endsWith(".mtl") || files.endsWith(".MTL"))
           {

              first = new JRadioButton(files);
              panel.add(first,BorderLayout.CENTER);
              panel.revalidate(); 

              bg.add(first);
              first.addActionListener(new MyAction);
            }
         }
      }

       frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
       frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(panel), BorderLayout.CENTER);
       frame.setSize(1000, 400);
       frame.setVisible(true);
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   }

  public class MyAction implements ActionListener{
        //String m;
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
      String m =e.getActionCommand();
      String[] split = m.split("\\.");
      m=split[0];
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your Selection is"+m+" radio button.");
   }
        /*
        public String getString(){
               return m;
        }
        */
   }
 }
```

Comment: What is the jlink tag for? I've never heard of this animal. Which line causes your NPE to be thrown?

Comment: Your getString() method would likely work if you made m a "bound property" using PropertyChangeSupport and allowing other classes to add PropertyChangeListeners to MyAction. That can be a little difficult at your stage. An even easier solution is to simply pass a reference to the SelectRadioButton instance into your MyAction class so that the Action can call a public method of SelectRadioButton and display the selected String.

Comment: I'm creating aaplications for the Pro-Engineer software. So J-Link is the api that ProE uses.

Comment: I'm not sure where would that go in my code...can you explain me a bit?dO I need to create a method like setString in SolidProperties? or something else?thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, the `m` variable only will be set when the specific radio button receive a click event.
 If you don't want to change your code so much, do something like this:

```
public class MyAction implements ActionListener{
    String m;

    public MyAction(String radioButtonLabel){
        m = radioButtonLabel;
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "Your Selection is"+m+" radio button.");
    }
    public String getString(){
        return m;
    }
}
```

And replace the:

```
first.addActionListener(new MyAction());
```

by:

```
first.addActionListener(new MyAction(files));
```

And improve the names of your variables... it is a little bit confusing!
Hope it helps.

**UPDATE**

To get the selected radio button:

```
public static JRadioButton getSelection(ButtonGroup group) {
    for (Enumeration e = group.getElements(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
        JRadioButton b = (JRadioButton) e.nextElement();
        if (b.getModel() == group.getSelection()) {
            return b;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: what's the "files" parameter?

Comment: @shaleen I just copy from your code, it's the String label of the radio button.

Comment: @ Elias thanks. I tried it, but now its just returning the last radio button value, and not the selected value...I'm open to change the code if I understand it..

Comment: @shaleen You need to use the `ButtonGroup` variable to get the selected radio button.